# Is there a way to have threads communicate with each other?

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi I am trying to make it so 2 threads will change the other one but I can't figure it out this is an example of what I have

```
Import time
Import threading
s=0

def thing1():
        time.sleep(1)
        s+=1
def thing2():
        print(s)

t = threading.Thread(target = thing1)
t.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target = thing2)
t2.start()
```

When they run thing2 will print 0, not the seconds. I have it so they run later this is just all the code that's necessary

Comment: `thing2` needs to be in some kind of loop

Comment: Use a semaphore so `thing1` can signal to `thing2` when it has updated the variable.

Comment: What is a semaphore?

Comment: There are no threads in the code you are showing, just two functions. How are you actually creating and running the threads? A [mcve], please.

Comment: `thing1` won't even run; you are trying to update an uninitialized local variable, not the global variable `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a semaphore so that each thread is not accessing the variable at the same time.  However, any two threads can access the same variable `s` using `global`.

```py
import threading
import time
s = 0
sem = threading.Semaphore()

def thing1():
    global s
    for _ in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)
        sem.acquire()
        s += 1
        sem.release()

def thing2():
    global s
    for _ in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)
        sem.acquire()
        print(s)
        sem.release()

t = threading.Thread(target = thing1)
t.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target = thing2)
t2.start()
```